# invisible array elements

Tags: c#

messagebox  showing each of array elements 1 to 9 but not showing 10 and 11th elements ?? 
WHy I can't reach 10th and 11 elements 
I tryied to do with richtext box too but I can't see again

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int i;
    int[] array1 = new array1[11];
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            array1[i] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) % 10;
            MessageBox.Show(dizi[i].ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            if (i > 11)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("it can't be big than 11");
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: 11 doesn't exist because the array is between 0-10

Comment: I wonder if there's an exception being thrown to give you information about what's wrong.  It sure would be nice if you could see that exception instead of just ignoring it in your code...

Comment: Also, i'm sure that code doesn't even compile. `int[] array = new array[11]` ? and where is `dizi` defined?

Comment: I edited now...sorry for writing dizi

Answer (score 2):

when `i == 10`, you will see the 11th element of the Array. That is because array indices start with `0`, so `i` goes from `0` to `10`. `11` or a higher number will give you an exception. I suggest you check it before trying to access the array though. like this:

```
if (i < 11) {       // or if (i < dizi.Length)
    try
    {
        dizi[i] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(dizi[i].ToString());
        i++;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        // You can still get errors if the text cannot be parsed to an int 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you already got your answer but yes really be careful about variables limits.

```
Type        Size (in bits)       Range
 -----           --------            ----------
sbyte           8               -128 to 127
byte            8                0 to 255
short           16              -32768 to 32767
ushort          16               0 to 65535
int                 32              -2147483648 to 2147483647
uint            3                    0 to 4294967295
long            64                  -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
ulong           64               0 to 18446744073709551615
char            16               0 to 65535 
float           32               7 digits 1.5 x 10-45 to 3.4 x 1038
Double              64               15-16 digits 5.0 x 10-324 to 1.7 x 10308
Decimal         128              28-29 decimal places 1.0 x 10-28 to 7.9 x 1028
```

Comment: A byte is 87 bits? Wow, that's some crazy CPU architecture you've got there.

Comment: Also; this question *seems* to relate to the array origin; 0-based vs 1-based. Not quite sure how this answer relates to the question, which makes it very odd that it was immediately accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value for an `int` is 2147483647 so if you were typing any number larger than that, `int.Parse()` would have failed silently. And as others have mentioned, there is no 11th element.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. You could simply use `MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);` but I'm sure there's a reason you were casting to `int` first.

Comment: cause I am using this numbers for algorithm and all numbers in TextBox is important for me